# How do I read a .env file from a .ps1 script?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have a `.env` file like this one:

```
TESTCASE_GROUP_SIZE=25
. . .
```

And I want to get its value (read it) into a `.ps1` script.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
get-content test.env | foreach {
    $name, $value = $_.split('=')
    set-content env:\$name $value
}
```

assuming you mean "set one environment variable per line in the file".

Comment: And then how do I call my variables?? Like TESTCASE_GROUP_SIZE

Comment: You can use `$env:TESTCASE_GROUP_SIZE` , but environment variables are really so you can launch a program and it inherits them as its environment. If that's not what you're doing then they may be better in a hashtable rather than as individual variables.

Comment: You might want to enclose the body of the `foreach` in `if ($_) { }` to filter empty lines. Heck, you might as well filter the comments in the env file using patterns.

Comment: If your values might have = in them, you'll want to add a second argument to `split()` so it doesn't toss them out: `$_.split('=',2)`

Comment: Worked for me in PS version 5.1 just had to drop the backslash on the set-content line: `set-content env:$name $value`

Comment: You could also use `new-Variable -Name $name -Value $value` if you want a local variable instead of an environment variable

Answer (score 14):

Polished version of @TessellatingHeckler's for future reference.

```
Get-Content .env | foreach {
  $name, $value = $_.split('=')
  if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($name) || $name.Contains('#')) {
    continue
  }
  Set-Content env:\$name $value
}
```

Comment: very nice! I like that you care about comments too!

Answer (score 5):

Throwing my hat into the ring. Powershell's `ConvertFrom-StringData` will ignore comments and handle edge cases like multiple `=` signs.

Run `notepad $PROFILE` and copy it in to make it available any time you open the terminal.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Imports variables from an ENV file

.EXAMPLE
# Basic usage
dotenv

.EXAMPLE
# Provide a path
dotenv path/to/env

.EXAMPLE
# See what the command will do before it runs
dotenv -whatif

.EXAMPLE
# Create regular vars instead of env vars
dotenv -type regular
#>
function Import-Env {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('dotenv')]
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $Path = '.env',

        # Determines whether variables are environment variables or normal
        [ValidateSet('Environment', 'Regular')]
        [String] $Type = 'Environment'
    )
    $Env = Get-Content -raw $Path | ConvertFrom-StringData
    $Env.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
        $Name, $Value = $_.Name, $_.Value
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Name, "Importing $Type Variable")) {
            switch ($Type) {
                'Environment' { Set-Content -Path "env:\$Name" -Value $Value }
                'Regular' { Set-Variable -Name $Name -Value $Value -Scope Script }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version 2 with Bash quoting rules by request of @YvesMartin

```
function Import-Env {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('dotenv')]
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $Path = '.env',

        # Determines whether variables are environment variables or normal
        [ValidateSet('Environment', 'Regular')]
        [String] $Type = 'Environment'
    )
    $Env = Get-Content -raw $Path | ConvertFrom-StringData
    $Env.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
        $Name, $Value  = $_.Name, $_.Value
        
        # Account for quote rules in Bash
        $StartQuote = [Regex]::Match($Value, "^('|`")")
        $EndQuote = [Regex]::Match($Value, "('|`")$")
        if ($StartQuote.Success -and -not $EndQuote.Success) {
            throw [System.IO.InvalidDataException] "Missing terminating quote $($StartQuote.Value) in '$Name': $Value"
        } elseif (-not $StartQuote.Success -and $EndQuote.Success) {
            throw [System.IO.InvalidDataException] "Missing starting quote $($EndQuote.Value) in '$Name': $Value"
        } elseif ($StartQuote.Value -ne $EndQuote.Value) {
            throw [System.IO.InvalidDataException] "Mismatched quotes in '$Name': $Value"
        } elseif ($StartQuote.Success -and $EndQuote.Success) {
            $Value = $Value -replace "^('|`")" -replace "('|`")$"  # Trim quotes
        }
        
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Name, "Importing $Type Variable")) {
            switch ($Type) {
                'Environment' { Set-Content -Path "env:\$Name" -Value $Value }
                'Regular' { Set-Variable -Name $Name -Value $Value -Scope Script }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really good. In case of cross-platform dotenv file (for Linux), we can expect declaration like `KEY="value1 value2"` produces same result as original Powershell `$Env:KEY="value1 value2"` than means $Env:KEY container `value1 value2` without double quotes. May you please propose a support for this?

Comment: Found an implementation at https://github.com/stopthatastronaut/poshdotenv/blob/master/module/dotenv/functions/Push-DotEnv.ps1#L101-L107

Comment: @YvesMartin It's kind of a tall order to do this properly as Bash is evaluating the env file as source code but I did what I could. An easier approach would be to call `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` on the value so the quotes are evaluated to the raw string. However, doing that carries risk because it would then eval any Powershell code in the string. In the absence of a string parser, making sure the string is valid is a bit of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this script:

```
get-content .env | foreach {
        $index = $_.IndexOf('=');
        $key = ''
        $value =''
        if ($index -ge 0) {
            $key = $_.Substring(0, $index)
            $value = $_.Substring($index + 1)
        }
        @{ $key = $value} 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Polished and actually working version of what was said above:

```
Set-Variable EnvFileRelLoc -Option Constant -Value "../../../docker/.env";

Get-Content $EnvFileRelLoc | foreach {
$name, $value = [regex]::split($_, '(?<= |\w+)=(?= |\W+)') ;
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($name) -OR $name.Contains('#') -OR $name.Contains('=')) {
    #   do nothing
} else {
    Write-host "NAME: $name ; VALUE $value";
    Set-Content env:$name $value
}
```

}

Comment: Anyway to get this to work for a value that contains "==" in the string?

Answer (score 0):

To make this easy to access:

1. Open your Powershell profile (for example with notepad using `notepad $PROFILE`).
2. Copy the following code (@jeiea's answer wrapped in a function):

```
function LoadEnvFile {
  Get-Content .env | foreach {
    $name, $value = $_.split('=')
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($name) || $name.Contains('#')) {
      continue
    }
    Set-Content env:\$name $value
  }
}
```

3. Once you save the profile and restart your shell, you can run `ReadEnvFile` anywhere to load an .env file in the same directory.

Feel free to swap the contents of the function with anyone else's answer if you like it more.